# css "top" stopping on screen keyboard on windows 7

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I'm using asp.net c# site. I've got the following 2 textboxes one with 2 different css parameters:-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuestion1Input" runat="server" CssClass="QT2Input"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"  CssClass="QT3Input"></asp:TextBox>
```

The css code is:-

```
.QT2Input
{
    position:absolute;
    left:200px;
    top:410px;
    width:400px;
}

.QT3Input
{
    position:absolute;
    left:200px;
    width:400px;
}
```

The client pc is connected to a touchscreen. when you click the textbox textbox2 it comes up with a symbol to bring up the on screen keyboard if you click it. if you click on txtQuestion1Input it doesn't show this symbol but if I get rid of top:410px; it works. Any ideas how to get round this please or why it's not working.

Many thanks

Comment: I'd start looking for other elements (with transparent backgrounds) that are positioned over the `<input>`. Such an element would prevent the focus from going to the `<input>`.

Comment: Hey Pointy, it's literally just those controls on a page with the css.

Comment: Please see [link]{http://jsfiddle.net/nhne5ygw/)